# Is it possible to check if a logical partition exist in Azure Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Is there any Partition key not found exception when we query with partitionkey via QueryRequestOptions? or is there any other ways I can be notified that the logical partition does not exist in a query?

Comment: `or is there any other ways I can be notified that the logical partition does not exist in a query?` - Do you want to get notified if the query does not contain partition key or do you want to get notified if there's no data based on the partition key value you provided?

Comment: i want to get notified if there is the logical partition does not exist. For example, I specified query with QueryRequestOptions queryRequestOptions = new QueryRequestOptions() { PartitionKey = "newPartition that does not exist in container"};, can I be thrown with partition key does not exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any Partition key not found exception when we query with
> partitionkey via QueryRequestOptions?

Assuming you are talking about the value of the partition key, as far as I know there is no such thing in Cosmos DB.

> or is there any other ways I can be notified that the logical
> partition does not exist in a query?

One possible way to find out is query your container with the partition key value in the query and try to fetch at most one document. If you don't get any documents back (i.e. get empty resultset), that would mean the logical partition does not exist in the container.

Comment: Yup, however such an alternative would result in unnecessary RU cost.

Comment: Agreed. But think of it in this way - Assuming Cosmos DB provided an endpoint to check for the existence of a logical partition, you would have incurred RUs to query that endpoint in any case.

Comment: Yes. The cheapest approach would have been Cosmos DB throwing an error straight to us if the partition does the exist.

Comment: Even that would cost you RUs.

Comment: But it no extra round trip is required for checking (additional RU) will be caused for those where the partition exist

Comment: There will be a round trip as you’ll be making a request to Cosmos DB service.